# fabric js how to use globalCompositeOperation in groups

Tags: fabricjs

I am trying to create groupe using fabricjs

```
var group = new fabric.Group(
   [ circle, this.callerObject ],
   {globalCompositeOperation:'xor'}
);
console.log(group);
this.mainCanvas.add(group);
```

But which globalCompositeOperation I have not set it is not working it always give the same result. I can make it using clear canvas, but I want to know, can I do it using native fabricjs methods?

Answer (score 2):

I find solution myself)) to make it work need add globalCompositeOperation to the second object.

```
 this.callerObject.set('globalCompositeOperation','xor');
 var group = new fabric.Group(
   [ circle, this.callerObject ]
);
```

But it have new problem)) this is work across all images)

To solve problem with cross showing

I have convert group to dataUrl, and to save state of object create new group, with object and image from previous group.

`createXorGroup: function(object){
        var self = this;
        var baseStateTop = this.callerObject.top;
        var baseStateLeft = this.callerObject.left;
        this.callerObject.set('globalCompositeOperation','xor');
        this.callerObject.set('active', false);
        var group = new fabric.Group([ object, this.callerObject ]);
        fabric.Image.fromURL(
            group.toDataURL(),
            function(image){
                image.setOriginToCenter && image.setOriginToCenter();
                self.callerObject.set('globalCompositeOperation','source-over');
                self.callerObject.set('opacity', 0);
                group = new fabric.Group([ self.callerObject, image ]);
                self.mainCanvas.add(group);
                group.setOriginToCenter && group.setOriginToCenter();
                group.set('top', baseStateTop).set('left', baseStateLeft).setCoords();
                group.setCenterToOrigin && group.setCenterToOrigin();
                self.mainCanvas.remove(self.callerObject);
                group.inCircle = true;
                group.set('active', true);
            },
            {
                originX: 'center',
                originY: 'center',
                top: this.callerObject.top,
                left: this.callerObject.left
            }
        );
    }`

It is not native fabricjs object, I have override some properties for my work, but I hope you understand the main aim and it will be helpful

Continue to work with this library
To make xor to svg I have write this:
`setGlobalCompositeOperation: function(object, type){
        if(object.imageType == 'svg'){
            for (var i = 0; i < object.paths.length; i++) {
               this.setGlobalCompositeOperation(object.paths[i], type);
            }
        }else{
            object.set('globalCompositeOperation', type);
        }
    }`

But this do not work for text in mozila 31.6.0(( I'm looking solution for text